# Filters for products

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have query for filters:

```
 public function filter(Request $request)
{

  $category_id = $request->category;
  $brand_id = $request->brand;
  $filters = $request->filters;

  if($brand_id == null){
    $products = Products::with('brand')->whereHas('category',function($q) use($category_id){
      $q->where('category_id', $category_id);
    })->whereHas('filters',function($q) use($filters){
      $q->where('filter_id', $filters);
    })->paginate(9);
  }else{
    $products = Products::with('brand')->where('brand_id',$brand_id)->whereHas('category',function($q) use($category_id){
      $q->where('category_id', $category_id);
    })->whereHas('filters',function($qw) use($filters){
      $qw->where('filter_id', $filters);
    })->paginate(9);
  }

  //Брэнды всех товаров
  $Brands = array();
  foreach ($products as $product) {
    if(!in_array($product->brand, $Brands)){
      array_push($Brands, $product->brand);
    }
  }

  return response()->json(['products' => $products,'brands' => $Brands]);
}
```

I get response only for first product, but i need to get all products which  contain at least one filter from the list.How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a small refactor + i'm not sure if you receive an array of filters or just a single id. If you need more than 1 id, use `whereIn`.

If you want to make this even cleaner, you can create Eloquent scope for filters and brands.

```
public function filter(Request $request)
{
  $categoryId = $request->category;
  $brandId = $request->brand;
  $filters = $request->filters;

  $query = Products::with('brand');

  if ($brandId) {
    $query = $query->where('brand_id', $brandId);
  }

  if ($filters) {
    $query = $query->whereHas('filters', function($q) use ($filters) {
        // If you have more than one filter id, use whereIn
        // $q->where('filter_id', $filters);
        $q->whereIn('filter_id', (array) $filters);
    });
  }

  if ($categoryId) {
    $query = $query->whereHas('category', function($q) use ($categoryId) {
        $q->where('category_id', $categoryId);
    });
  }

  $products = $query->paginate(9);

  $brands = $products->total() > 0 ? $products->items()->pluck('brand')->all() : [];

  return response()->json(compact('products', 'brands'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use whereIn() function instead of where() when query products